# Inconsistent results when concatenating parsed csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I am puzzled with the following problem. I have a set of csv files, which I parse iterativly. Before collecting the dataframes in a list, I apply some function (as simple as `tmp_df*2`) to each of the `tmp_df`. It all worked perfectly fine at first glance, until I've realized I have inconsistencies with the results from run to run.
For example, when I apply `df.std()` I might receive for a first run:

```
In[2]:  df1.std()
Out[2]:
  some_int      15281.99
  some_float    5.302293
```

and for a second run after:

```
In[3]:  df2.std()
Out[3]:
  some_int      15281.99
  some_float    6.691013
```

Strangly, I don't not observe inconsistencies like this one when I don't manipulate the parsed data (simply comment out `tmp_df = tmp_df*2`). I also noticed that for the columns where I have datatypes `int` the results are consistent from run to run, which does not hold for `floats`. I suspect it has to do with the precision points. I also cannot establish a pattern how they vary, it might be that I have the same results for two or three consecutive runs. Maybe someone has an idea if I am missing something here. I am working on a replication example, I'll edit asap, as I cannot share the underlying data. Maybe someone can shed some light on this in the meantime. I am using win8.1, pandas 17.1, python 3.4.3.

Code example:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 data_list = list()
 csv_files = ['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv']

 for csv_file in csv_files:

    #  load csv_file
    tmp_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col='ID', dtype=np.float64)

    # replace infs by na
    tmp_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)

    # manipulate tmp_df
    tmp_df = tmp_df*2

    data_list.append(tmp_df)

df = pd.concat(data_list, ignore_index=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Update:

Running the same code and data on a UX system works perfectly fine.

Edit:
I have managed to re-create the problem, it should run on win and ux. I've tested on win8.1 facing the same problem when `with_function=True` (typically after 1-5 runs), on ux the it runs without problems. `with_function=False` runs without differences for win and ux. I can also reject the hypothesis that it is related to `int` or `float` issue as also the simulated `int` are different...

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import gettempdir


def simulate_csv_data(tmp_dir,num_files=5):
    """ simulate a csv files
    :param tmp_dir: Path, csv files are saved to
    :param num_files: int, how many csv files to simulate
    :return:
    """

    rows = 20000
    columns = 5
    np.random.seed(1282)

    for file_num in range(num_files):

        file_path = tmp_dir.joinpath(''.join(['df_', str(file_num), '.csv']))
        simulated_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((rows, columns)))
        simulated_df['some_int'] = np.random.randint(0,100)
        simulated_df.to_csv(str(file_path))


def get_csv_data(tmp_dir,num_files=5, with_function=True):
    """ Collect various csv files and return a concatenated dfs
    :param tmp_dir: Path, csv files are saved to
    :param num_files: int, how many csv files to simulate
    :param with_function: Bool, apply function to tmp_dataframe
    :return:
    """

    data_list = list()

    for file_num in range(num_files):
        # current file path
        file_path = tmp_dir.joinpath(''.join(['df_', str(file_num), '.csv']))

        #  load csv_file
        tmp_df = pd.read_csv(str(file_path), dtype=np.float64)

        # replace infs by na
        tmp_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)

        # apply function to tmp_dataframe
        if with_function:
            tmp_df = tmp_df*2

        data_list.append(tmp_df)

    df = pd.concat(data_list, ignore_index=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    return df

def main():

    # INPUT ----------------------------------------------
    num_files = 5
    with_function = True
    max_comparisons = 50
    # ----------------------------------------------------

    tmp_dir = gettempdir()
    # use temporary "non_existing" dir for new file
    tmp_csv_folder = Path(tmp_dir).joinpath('csv_files_sdfs2eqqf')

    # if exists already don't simulate data/files again
    if tmp_csv_folder.exists() is False:
        tmp_csv_folder.mkdir()
        print('Simulating temp files...')
        simulate_csv_data(tmp_csv_folder, num_files)

    print('Getting benchmark data frame...')
    df1 = get_csv_data(tmp_csv_folder, num_files, with_function)
    df_is_same = True
    count_runs = 0

    # Run until different df is found or max runs exceeded
    print('Comparing data frames...')
    while df_is_same:
        # get another data frame
        df2 = get_csv_data(tmp_csv_folder, num_files, with_function)
        count_runs += 1
        # compare data frames
        if df1.equals(df2) is False:
            df_is_same = False
            print('Found unequal df after {} runs'.format(count_runs))
            # print out a standard deviations (arbitrary example)
            print('Std Run1: \n {}'.format(df1.std()))
            print('Std Run2: \n {}'.format(df2.std()))

        if count_runs > max_comparisons:
            df_is_same = False
            print('No unequal df found after {} runs'.format(count_runs))

    print('Delete the following folder if no longer needed: "{}"'.format(
            str(tmp_csv_folder)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hard to tell without the repro data, might be a bug in Pandas - have a look at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mul do you have the same problem if you you manipulate `df` instead of each `tmp_df`?

Comment: I simplified the example, in that case I could apply the function 2x also to `df` but I actually need to apply some `tmp_df`-dependent function. As the problem occurs already with 2x I wanted to keep it simple...

Comment: i've just added an example which replicates the problem..

Comment: not sure what do you expect from SO if your are suggesting that it is a bug on windows implementation of pandas

Comment: I added it to pandas issue tracker. Initially, I wasn't aware of this being a windows issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP already reported this as a Pandas bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating numexpr to 2.4.6 (or later), as numexpr 2.4.4 had some bugs on windows. After running the update it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your variations are caused by something else, like input data change between executions, or source code changes.

Float precision does not ever gives different results between executions.

Btw, clean your examples and you will find the bug. At this moment you say something about and int but display a decimal value instead!!

Comment: The raw data types are different (int and float, though I parse them as float) in that case it's the standard deviation which I display, which is not an int. I don't know how input data should change, as the problem only occurs when I apply a function to the raw_data, and the function does not change...